# submitting value of <select> field inside div in form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

i am trying to submit values of form.
but all values other than a `<select>` field is not submitted because i think its inside div element as shown in code below

```
<form action="next.php" method="post">
     <input>....
     <input>....
     <input>....
     <select name="asdf"> <!--This field submitted successfully -->
         <option value="wtevr"> </option>
         <option value="wtevr2"> </option>..........
     </select>
     <div>
         <select name="asdf2"> <!--problem is here submitting this field -->
             <option value="wtevr11"> </option>
             <option value="wtevr22"> </option>..........
         </select>
     </div>
</form>
```

I used `div` because this is part of my ajax code through which i update the values in select field.
Is there any alternative solution to submit this `select` field form?

**MY approach:**

I think that there is a solution if i use a `hidden` `input` field in this form whose value get equal to value of select field before submitted the form.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<!--comes from JavaScript code -->">
```

I am new to JavaScript so any help is appreciated..

Comment: 'values (...) are not submitted' - Are you sure? Can we see your `$_POST` array from next.php (use `print_r($_POST)`)

Comment: Also show the bit of javascript you're using to set the value in the select. Thanks.

Comment: Is the form submitted normally, or do you attempt an ajax submit?

Comment: They are serializing just fine. Look at the console. http://jsbin.com/zaruceke/1/edit

Comment: sorry i found the bug the problem is with my ajax code i fix that.
thanks for @Gwenc37 for `print_r` code suggestion 
and 
@user574632 for pointing my ajax code and all others

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
<select name="asdf2" id="asdf2" onchange="setField();">
            <option value="this">this</option>
            <option value="that">that</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="nothingYet">
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
function setField() {
            toWhat = document.getElementById("asdf2").value
            document.getElementById("hiddenField").value = toWhat;
        }
</script>
```

In any case.  If all you're doing is submitting the form, there really is no reason for that value to be ignored.  How are you retrieving the values?

Comment: Well, now you know a new JS trick you can use going forward.  I think you'll find things like this areextremely common for usage when you are not using, say, jQuerry.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'name' tag in your inputs, then they'll be submitted.
like this:

```
<form action="next.php" method="post">
<input name="foo" value="var"/>
</form>
```

Comment: He is specifically asking about the second select field, which does have a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` tag has a property called [form=""].
With that you can assign it to a form element.
As the form gets submitted, the select element is included.

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" name =...>
    <select name="selectelement" form="myform">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: ```myForm``` should be the id of the form. Doesn't work if used as the name attribute